# In a Chrome app cannot unpause TCP connection for TCP server

Tags: javascript, sockets, tcp, google-chrome-app, tcpserver

I'm trying to set up a TCP server in a Chrome app. I'm very close to being done. I can send data from my TCP server to my client. But I can't process the data sent BY the client. I figured out that the socket is paused. The thing is, I can't seem to un-pause it.

If I try this in the JavaScript console:

```
chrome.sockets.tcp.getSockets(function(d) {console.log(d);});
```

I get this result:

```
[Object]
  0: Object
    connected: true
    localAddress: "127.0.0.1"
    localPort: 60519
    paused: true
    peerAddress: "127.0.0.1"
    peerPort: 36529
    persistent: false
    socketId: 11
    length: 1
```

So then I just unpause it, right? Like this:

```
chrome.sockets.tcpServer.setPaused(
  socketID, false, function () {
    console.log('unpaused');
   }
);
```

And indeed my callback is run:

```
unpaused
```

But if I check again

```
chrome.sockets.tcp.getSockets(function(d) {console.log(d);});
```

I *still* get:

```
[Object]
  0: Object
    connected: true
    localAddress: "127.0.0.1"
    localPort: 60519
    paused: true
    peerAddress: "127.0.0.1"
    peerPort: 36529
    persistent: false
    socketId: 11
    length: 1
```

For the socketID value in the call to setPaused, I've used both the value Chrome gave me for socketID and for clientSocketID. Neither one seems to unpause my socket.

EDIT:

I also tried getInfo():

```
chrome.sockets.tcpServer.getInfo(19, function (d) {console.log(d);});
```

which returned, to my great surprise:

```
Object {
  localAddress: "127.0.0.1",
  localPort: 60519,
  paused: false,
  persistent: false,
  socketId: 19
}
```

getSockets() still says that the socket is paused. The socket is still not receiving messages. I'm very confused.

For the sake of completeness, here's how I'm trying to process messages:

```
Package.MyClass.prototype.onAccept = function(info) {
  console.log('accept info', info);
  if (info.socketId !== this.serverSocketId) { return;}
  console.log('Socket ID is correct.'); // This gets printed every time.

  // Start receiving data.
  chrome.sockets.tcp.onReceive.addListener(this.onReceive.bind(this));
  chrome.sockets.tcpServer.setPaused(this.serverSocketId, false);
}
```

I can tell that onAccept() is called when the client connects to the socket: the console log shows that. But onReceive also starts with a call to console.log and that never shows up.

EDIT:
SOLVED:

I found a workaround: I used this script instead: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/tcpserver/tcp-server.js

It does everything I need and it's much easier to use and configure.

Comment: You've tried `...setPaused(11, false)`?

Comment: That's the clientSocketId. Yes, I've tried with both the socketId (in my case, 19) and the regular socketId.

Comment: If you have the solution, enter it as an answer so you can mark it as the answer.

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained why the first code didn't work and the second did. Otherwise other readers won't learn from your mistakes. One thing to note: it's unusual to set up listeners in an I/O event listener. It implies that you want to add a new listener each time you accept a connection. More typically the event listeners are all set up and ready, and then the I/O is kicked off.

Comment: @MarcRochkind This seemed less of a solution and more of a workaround, but if you think it counts as a solution, I'll make an answer out of it.

Comment: @sowbug That code looked very strange to me too. But it was Google's example. The whole documentation was littered with inaccurate references to the API and there was even a typo in the code. It looked like it had never been proofread. I think this part of Chrome is still very experimental and simply not mature. I deleted my code that used Chrome's own TCP server without saving it to version control, but you can find the example I used here: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_network#tcpServer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my final edit, I found a workaround: I used this script instead: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/tcpserver/tcp-server.js

It does everything I need and it's much easier to use and configure.

It just seems that the built-in TCP server is not functional as per the current version of Chrome, Chrome 34.